# How do I pass a scraped URL back into BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have scraped a page and gathered the URLs that on on the site. I was then trying to pass those found URLs back into BS to open them and scrape them for

. This might be something super simple I am missing and I apologize for that. I've only started python this last week.

Here is my code.

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests

    # gets website
    html_text = requests.get('https://www.marketwatch.com/latest-news?mod=top_nav').text
    # uses BeautifulSoup to read the html
    website = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
    # searches the html that BS read into py
    stories = website.find('div', class_='collection__elements j-scrollElement')
    # searches stories for a single story
    story = stories.find('div', class_='element element--article')
    # searches story for the headline
    article_headline = story.find('h3', class_='article__headline').text
    # get link to article from the head line to then pass through to get the articles content
    possible_links = story.find_all('a', class_='link')
    for link in possible_links:
        linkArt = (link.get('href'))
    print('Link:' + linkArt) # make sure expected link was found

    # Pass found link back into a request (part that doesn't work)
    article_html = requests.get(linkArt).text
    article = BeautifulSoup(article_html, ' lxml')

    article_wrapper = article.find('div', class_ = 'column column--full article__content')
    article_content = article_wrapper.find_all('p').text
```

This is my error:
Link:https://www.marketwatch.com/articles/global-stocks-edge-lower-with-biden-adopting-traditional-dollar-stance-chinese-equities-gain-after-gdp-report-51610967473?mod=newsviewer_click
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\MLG420\PycharmProjects\scraper\scrape.py", line 23, in 
article = BeautifulSoup(article_html, ' lxml')
File "C:\Users\MLG420\PycharmProjects\scraper\venv\lib\site-packages\bs4_*init*_.py", line 243, in **init**
raise FeatureNotFound(
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested:  lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?

Comment: You have a simple typo: an additional space before `lxml` in the `article =` line.

Comment: *facepalm*.... thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were 2 errors: there is a space in `" lxml"` that breaks the code in the declaration of `article_html` and in the last line you are calling `.text` on a list.
Here's the corrected code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml

# gets website
html_text = requests.get('https://www.marketwatch.com/latest-news?mod=top_nav').text
# uses BeautifulSoup to read the html
website = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
# searches the html that BS read into py
stories = website.find('div', class_='collection__elements j-scrollElement')
# searches stories for a single story
story = stories.find('div', class_='element element--article')
# searches story for the headline
article_headline = story.find('h3', class_='article__headline').text
# get link to article from the head line to then pass through to get the articles content
possible_links = story.find_all('a', class_='link')
for link in possible_links:
    linkArt = (link.get('href'))
print('Link:' + linkArt) # make sure expected link was found

# Pass found link back into a request (part that doesn't work)
article_html = requests.get(linkArt).text
article = BeautifulSoup(article_html, 'lxml')

article_wrapper = article.find('div', class_ = 'column column--full article__content')
article_content = article_wrapper.find_all('p')
for elem in article_content:
    print(elem.text)  # or do something else
```